# Haskell: List Comprehension / Hash Table Entries

Tags: haskell, hashtable, list-comprehension

I'm trying to place a bunch of words into a hash table based on length.  The words are stored in

```
data Entry = Entry {word :: String, length :: Int} deriving Show
```

Now, I've got all the words stored in "entries", which is a list of Entry.  Then, my hash table is defined as follows:

```
type Hash = [Run]
type Run = [Entry]
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the entries into the hash table.  The following is my current attempt

```
maxL = maximum [length e | e <- entries]
runs = [r | r <- [e | e <- entries, length e == i]] where i = [1..maxL]
```

Compiler's obviously telling me that Int can't be compared to [Int], but I don't know how to say

```
e | e <- entries, e has length i
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: `[[Entry]]` is not a hash table, it's a list of lists of `Entry` records.

Comment: Hm.  I'm just following what my professors been telling me.  Is it not a hash table?  I have very little understanding of hash tables but aren't they just storing records in lists of lists, based on some hashing function?  In this case, the hashing function would be the length of the word

Comment: Describing the problem in this way makes it confusing. Just say that you want to group a list of strings by their lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost OK:

```
maxL = maximum [length e | e <- entries]
runs = [r | r <- [e | e <- entries, length e == i]] where i = [1..maxL]
```

except that `where` doesn't work that way. It's not a synonym for `foreach`; but for `let`:

```
runs = let i = [1..maxL] 
       in [r | r <- [e | e <- entries, length e == i]]
```

So, `length e` is an integer, but `i` is `[1..maxL]` which is a list of integers. You intended for `i` to take on the values in `[1..maxL]` one-by-one, and that's done by `<-` binding in list comprehension:

```
runs = [ [r | r <- [e | e <- entries, length e == i]] | i <- [1..maxL]]
```

Now, `[r | r <- xs]` is the same as just `xs`, so it becomes

```
runs = [ [e | e <- entries, length e == i] | i <- [1..maxL]]
```

With "standard" functions, this is written as

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord  (comparing)

runs = group $ sortBy (comparing length) entries
```

It is also better algorithmically. Although, it won't have empty runs for non-existent lengths, so the two aren't strictly equivalent. But that can be fixed with another `O(n)` pass over the results, with

```
-- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])

runs' = snd $ mapAccumL 
               (\a@ ~((k,g):t) i-> if null a || i<k then (a,[]) else (t,g))
               [ (length $ head g, g) | g<- runs]
               [ 1..maxL]
```

Comment: forgot to mention that `mapAccumL` is also from `Data.List`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3agroupBy) function from `Data.List`. You have a list of strings, which you want to group by their lengths. The `groupBy` function has type `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]`. The second parameter is your input list and the first is a function that you need to write, which should take two strings and compare their lengths. It will return a list of lists of strings, where each sub-list will be containing strings of equal length.

By the way, if you want to write this succinctly, look at the [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v%3aon) combinator from `Data.Function`.

Comment: Note: `groupBy` only groups adjacent items, so you'll want to sort by length first.

Comment: having sorted by `length`, simple `group` will suffice.